# Multi-Thread message filter for TwinCAT

Tags: c#, twincat, imessagefilter

I'm not experienced with C# so excuse me for my lack of knowledge..

I need to implement a COM Message filter for a multi-thread application(Background worker). I got send through to this(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms809971(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) site but it doesn't give an example of a working filter. 
I can't seem to find a multi-thread message filter online.. does anyone have an example code for this filter?

The error I'm getting is described on the Beckhoff site(https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_automationinterface/54043195771173899.html&id=, scroll down until you see the black administrator window, that's the error), but doesn't help me fix the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What message filter are you talking about and what would COM have to do with this? The MSDN link you posted shows nothing about filters. The second link talks about COM server applications.

Comment: The beckhoff site should explain this, COM Message filter and a Visual Studio COM Server. I think that's what you're asking for

Comment: It doesn't exlain anything. What are you building? Why do you care about *COM* messages to begin with? That's 30-year old technology. It's *you* who is asking and needs to provide sufficient information for people to help you. In any case you don't need to use COM to run something in the background

Comment: Very few people remember the COM days, and those that do would say that they don't understand what you're asking, or what a site that seems to talk about old hardware devices have to do with C#

Comment: I am building an application which creates a Visual studio solution for a TwinCAT project. I need this filter because I get messages like "CALL_REJECTED" and "RETRYLATER". This will crash the application. I get your point, sorry for my lack of experience.

Comment: I tagged your question TwinCAT so it makes some sense - otherwise people will ask why you need 20yr old tech.

Comment: Google "c# coregistermessagefilter" to find the code you need.  It is a bit ironic that the beckhoff page is listed first however.  Do keep in mind that without that filter it is trying to tell you that you are using it wrong.  Pummeling it with calls from a worker thread or console app is using it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a com message filter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Collections;

namespace TwincatCodeGenerator
{
    [ComImport(),Guid("00000016-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"),InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IOleMessageFilter{
        [PreserveSig]
        int HandleInComingCall(int dwCallType, IntPtr hTaskCaller, int dwTickCount, IntPtr lpInterfaceInfo);
        [PreserveSig]
        int RetryRejectedCall(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwRejectType);
        [PreserveSig]
        int MessagePending(IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwPendingType);
    }
    class MessageFilter : IOleMessageFilter
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            IOleMessageFilter newFilter = new MessageFilter();
            IOleMessageFilter oldFilter = null;
            int test = CoRegisterMessageFilter(newFilter, out oldFilter);
            if (test != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("CoRegisterMessageFilterfailed with error : {0}", test));
            }
        }

        public static void Revoke()
        {
            IOleMessageFilter oldFilter = null;
            int test = CoRegisterMessageFilter(null, out oldFilter);
        }

        int IOleMessageFilter.HandleInComingCall(int dwCallType, System.IntPtr hTaskCaller, int dwTickCount, System.IntPtr lpInterfaceInfo)
        {
            //returns the flag SERVERCALL_ISHANDLED.
            Console.WriteLine("HandleIncomingCall");
            return 0;
        }

        int IOleMessageFilter.RetryRejectedCall(System.IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwRejectType)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("RetryRejectedCall");
            // Thread call was refused, try again.
            if (dwRejectType == 2)
            // flag = SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER.
            {
                // retry thread call at once, if return value >=0 &
                // <100.
                return 99;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        int IOleMessageFilter.MessagePending(System.IntPtr hTaskCallee, int dwTickCount, int dwPendingType)
        {//return flag PENDINGMSG_WAITDEFPROCESS.
            Console.WriteLine("Message Pending");
            return 2;
        }

        [DllImport("Ole32.dll")]private static extern int CoRegisterMessageFilter(IOleMessageFilter newFilter, out IOleMessageFilter oldFilter);
    }
}
```

call the filter in your  main method like this:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MessageFilter.Register();

        //Your code here
        //...

        MessageFilter.Revoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this as well!

Comment: Just write if you need more help

Comment: I forgot to mention that you obviously have to download the samples that are on the beckhoff Infosys page to find out how to build your com filter..

Comment: I implemented the filter that is used in the Beckhoff samples, this filter is giving me the errors. Should I add [STAThread] at the top of the function that is called on the second Thread?

Comment: I posted an example of a com message filter.